# Are saddle points considered unstable in practical applications?

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

Consider the system : $\ddot{x}=u+\frac{x-x_1}{\|x-x_1\|^3}$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $x_1 \neq 0$ , The requirement is to make the origin globally asymptotically stable by choosing a continuous control signal $u$ so I can't just say let $u=-\frac{x-x_1}{\|x-x_1\|^3} + f(x,\dot{x})$ as it is not continuous near $x=x_1$.

I tried some possible choices of $u$ . However I wasn't able to get rid of the saddle points .

****So my main question is : Can I use the fact that noises and disturbance rise in real world to say that these saddle points will be unstable when the controller is applied in real world ?****

I would also appreciate it if someone pointed out a good choice of $u$ , but please notice that this is not my main objective .

Comment: What are the restrictions on $\ u\ $, apart from continuity? In other words, what are the other conditions that it must satisfy to be feasible?

Comment: I think feasibility is not necessary in the sense that it doesn't grow unbounded as it does imply continuity .